# Mysql select where procedure=1

Tags: mysql, where-clause, procedure, dynamically-generated, having

I have procedure "CheckStatus" which returns 0 or 1.
How I can use this query without HAVING? It's not work properly with limit 0,10 - it filtering rows with status=0 and I never got 10 results as I expected. Yes I understand that HAVING w/o GROUP BY just filtering results and not rows.

How I can use status in WHERE?

```
select id,CheckStatus(stock,delivery_days) as `status` from new where 
id in ('52078','52093','52095','81584','81589') 
having status in ('1') 
order by field (id,'52078','52093','52095','81584','81589') group by id limit 0,10
```

Also maybe I can someway create generated column with this procedure? I tried to add it but got an error about I can't call procedure for generated columns.

Comment: You can't refer to `status` in the `WHERE` clause.  You either have to use your version or subquery.

Comment: I think you can replace `having status in ('1')` by `where CheckStatus(stock,delivery_days) in ('1')`

Comment: CheckStatus is  a function not a procedure..

Comment: btw `orderby`  comes next to `group by` so this will throw error.

Comment: A group by without any aggregate functions is rarely (if ever) useful.